# How to configure environment to prevent Microsoft messages from being logged?

Tags: logging, .net-core, amazon-ecs

I have a Microsoft DotNet Core 2.0 application running as an AWS ECS service, which sits behind a load balancer, and its Cloudwatch logs are filled with messages from the AspNetCore.Hosting layer because of the load balancer's health check invoking the application's status endpoint:

```
17:49:18 [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
17:49:18 Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.10.1.184/status
17:49:18 [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
17:49:18 Executing action method Controller.Controllers.StatusController.Status (MyEcsApplication) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
17:49:18 [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.Internal.JsonResultExecutor[1]
17:49:18 Executing JsonResult, writing value Controller.Models.StatusModel.
17:49:18 [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
17:49:18 Executed action Controller.Controllers.StatusController.Status (MyEcsApplication) in 4.8748ms
17:49:18 [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
17:49:18 Request finished in 32.7132ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

The application's log level is set to Debug, as I'm doing initial testing, and these messages make the logs very noisy.  Is there a way to configure logging to exclude messages from Microsoft.AspNetCore?

Here is my appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "AWS": {
    "Profile": "default",
    "Region": "us-east-1"
  },
  "Log4Net": {
    "ConfigFileRelativePath": "log4net.xml",
    "Repository": "NETCoreRepository"
  },
  "Swagger": {
    "FileName": "MyEcsApplication.xml"
  }
}
```

And the Program.cs startup code:  (edited to add ConfigureAppConfiguration)

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()  // use default web server on port 80
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
             {
                 logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                 logging.AddConsole();
                 logging.AddDebug();
             })
            .Build();

// run the web host and block until host shutdown
host.Run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your Logging LogLevel to something like this:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Microsoft": "Error",
    "Default": "Debug"
  }
}
```

Here is some documentation on filtering: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#log-filtering

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the documentation.  However, that configuration didn't stop the log messages from Microsoft.

Comment: I'm going to try adding a Console section with the Microsoft filter and see if that does it.

Comment: I've used the console part and I know that will prevent logging messages to the console.

Comment: Hmmm... still no luck.  I've added the Program.cs startup code to my post.  Am I missing something connecting things?

Comment: From the link you sent, I was not using ConfigureAppConfiguration() in my WebHostBuilder().  Adding that now, fingers crossed...

Comment: That was it, I was missing the call to ConfigureAppConfiguration(), so I guess it was never actually loading my appsettings.json settings.